# bad argument #1 to 'random' (number expected, got nil)

Tags: lua

Problem using `math.random` maybe?

Here's the code:

```
local combat = createCombatObject()
setCombatParam(combat, COMBAT_PARAM_EFFECT, CONST_ME_MAGIC_BLUE)
setCombatParam(combat, COMBAT_PARAM_AGGRESSIVE, false)

function onGetFormulaValues(cid, level, maglevel)
    local min = (((level/5)+(maglevel*1) +1))
    local max = (((level/5)+(maglevel*2) +3))
    return min, max
end

setCombatCallback(combat, CALLBACK_PARAM_LEVELMAGICVALUE, "onGetFormulaValues")

local condition = createConditionObject(CONDITION_REGENERATION)
setConditionParam(condition, CONDITION_PARAM_SUBID, 1)
setConditionParam(condition, CONDITION_PARAM_BUFF, true)
setConditionParam(condition, CONDITION_PARAM_TICKS, 1 * 60 * 1000)
setConditionParam(condition, CONDITION_PARAM_HEALTHGAIN, math.max(math.random(min, max)))
setConditionParam(condition, CONDITION_PARAM_HEALTHTICKS, 1000)
setCombatCondition(combat, condition)


function onCastSpell(cid, var)
    return doCombat(cid, combat, var)
end
```

Its says the errors is in line 17, which is the `math.random` one. I have very little knowledge in Lua and this code I got from a forum, that the person posted in 2012, so I can't ask them.

Comment: I don't understand the full context of the script, but it appears the value "min" is not defined. It is a local variable in the function onGetFormulaValues(), but it is being called (line 17) outside of the scope of that function. Try removing the 'local' keyword in front of min/max on lines 6/7, so that other parts of the script can access it. If this code block is all there is, then that shouldn't break anything.

Comment: Sorry for not explain.This script is a spell from a game. It was supposed to heal the player for 1 min each second, and the formula of the healing is determined by using his level and magic level. I try removing the "local" as you said, Alister, but i got the SAME error.

Comment: I still can't understand the callback at line 11 (I would recommend you post this question on the website of the game you're scripting, if they have a scripters forum), but I would try printing the values min/max inside the function onGetFormulaValues before the return line so we can determine if the value is not correctly being defined in scope or just a scope problem. How are you passing cid, level and maglevel to the function at line 5? If these are globals and you want to access them inside that function without passing them at line 11, take them out of the parentheses.